# bootstrap modal sharing image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, social-media

On the news section of a website that I am developing, when a news article is opened a bootstrap modal is opened. There is sharing links on the bottom of the article which is set to share like the below and when the link is clicked on you're brought to the right place

website.com/news#news_Article

My problem is that when the article is shared the correct image from the article is not shown. Does anyone know a way around this to include the correct image and title of the articles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not without seeing the code.

Comment: True, we need to see the code. Also, where are you sharing? any social media site? need to see the shared image to find the issue.